# WP v4.7 REST API v2 endpoints stopped filtering

Tags: wordpress

After updating to WordPress 4.7 WP REST api v2 endpoints stopped filtering. Any one else experiencing this? Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, same here after updating to 4.7 alla endpoints stop working, with a little digging i found this, https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/

WordPress 4.7 comes with REST API endpoints for posts, comments, terms, users, meta, and settings.

So i change for example /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[name]=something to /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=something